# Position uibuttons with auto-layout Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, autolayout

I have an `uiview` with two `uibuttons`.
The issue is - i cannot understand how to use `auto-layout constraints` in order to position them the following way
[image]

Thank you in advance for any insights!

Comment: this is not possible.. you need to keep one constraint dynamic according to screen size. eg. 15%-[btn1(25%)]--- Dynamic distance --- [btn2(25%)]-15%

Comment: @AshishP. lets assume then that dynamic constraint approach is fine. how do i implement it then?

Comment: Is this for Swift 1.2 or Swift 2? iOS 9 only?

Comment: @Abizern This is swift 2.0, I'm currently testing on iOS9, but i don't want it to be exclusive to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
   //Individual button Width
    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: button1, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, multiplier: 0.25, constant: 0))
    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: button2, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, multiplier: 0.25, constant: 0))

    //Button1 left spacing
    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: button1, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: self.view.frame.size.width * 0.15))

    //Button2 Right Spacing
    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: button2, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: -self.view.frame.size.width * 0.15))

    //Y placement
    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: button1, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: button1, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: button2, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
```

Also, you will need to reset the constraints on rotation as self.view.frame.size.width will change. It has been used to calculate the constraint constants.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to reset the constraints you can try to make the spacing constraints like this:

```
self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: button1, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 0.275, constant: 0))
self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: button2, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 0.625, constant: 0))
```

Note that the order of views is reversed.

I've used it successfully with IB, should work from code.